# sudo chown -R www-data & userexample /home/example/uploads

Tags: sudo, chown

when typing in PuTTY ***sudo chown -R www-data /home/example/uploads*** My website is displayed but I cannot access my FTP but when typing ***sudo chown -R example /home/example/uploads*** I can access my FTP but my website display an 403 Forbidden error

is there something similar possible: 
sudo chown -R www-data & userexample /home/example/uploads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a permissions issue. Try `chmod 644` to make a file readable to all (both you and the web server), or `chmod 755` for directories.

Perhaps even `chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX` to give proper access to directories as well: this asks to give the owner read-write permissions, keeping execute permission if it was there, and others (group and anyone) read permission, as well as execute if one of the classes of users already had exec permission.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works ! `chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX /home/example`

Comment: I spoke a bit too fast with the `644`... Try `find home/example/uploads -type d -exec chmod -c a+x {} +` to put the execution permission back on directories.